# An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration, not on every computer

Tags: c#, service, .net-core-2.2

I have 'An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.' error when running my code. But, not on every computer.

I'm registring services like this, everything seems to be ok.
But when running this code, I'm receiving error that tells me that these services are not registred. 
Funny fact is that this code works on one of 3 computers I've tried.
What can be wrong with this?

```
builder.RegisterType<DeliveryCalendarPlugin>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<HolidayCountryService>().As<IHolidayCountryService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<HolidayService>().As<IHolidayService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CustomCheckoutAttributeParser>().As<ICustomCheckoutAttributeParser>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

ERROR CODE:

No constructor was found that had all the dependencies satisfied. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = HolidayCountryService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Services.IHolidayCountryService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = EfRepository`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Domain.HolidayCountry, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IDbContext (DelegateActivator), Services = [nop_object_context_holiday (Nop.Data.IDbContext)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> The requested service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Data.HolidayObjectContext, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = EfRepository`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Domain.HolidayCountry, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IDbContext (DelegateActivator), Services = [nop_object_context_holiday (Nop.Data.IDbContext)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> The requested service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Data.HolidayObjectContext, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = IDbContext (DelegateActivator), Services = [nop_object_context_holiday (Nop.Data.IDbContext)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> The requested service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Data.HolidayObjectContext, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency. (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar.Data.HolidayObjectContext, Nop4you.Plugin.Widgets.DeliveryCalendar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Comment: look at your output directory dlls/files on the working computer and compare them to the other computers, i would venture a guess and say your missing a dll

Comment: @JohnChris they are the same... everything is the same.

Comment: ok then download the latest .net developer pack and install on machine that it doesnt work on  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net472-developer-pack

Comment: It is core 2.2 project, I forgot to mention it. So I think it wouldnt help